Expected (log)volume of projection of a cube onto a random subspace
Suppose $A$ is a full-rank $d\times d$ dimensional matrix. Let $U \in R^{d\times k}$ be a projection to projection matrix onto a uniformly chosen sub-space of dimension $k$ (for example, they can be the first $k$ column of a uniformly drawn rotation matrix in $R^d$). I am trying to calculate the following expectation:
$$
E \log \det (U^\top A^\top A U) 
$$
where the expectation is over $U.$ Essentially, we have a cube whose axes lengths are eigenvalues of $A^\top A,$ and we want to quantify the log-volume of the projection of this cube onto a randomly chosen sub-space with dimension $k.$
In my efforts to gain more insight into this, I tried two approaches:

Replacing with Gaussian: we can study this problem in the limit when $k \ll d.$ In this regime, we can replace $U$ with a Gaussian matrix of same size $W$ whose elements are drawn iid from $N(0,1/d)$. This is because when $d$ is sufficiently large, the norm of the $k$ Gaussian vectors will converge to their expectation one, and their inner products will converge to zero $W^\top W \to I_k.$ The advantage of replacing $U$ with $W$ is that now $X = A W$ is a Gaussian matrix and we can calculate $\log\det(X^\top X)$ in closed form, namely using results here or here.

Replacing rotation with permutation matrix: A subclass of rotation matrices are axis permutation matrices: Given permutation $\pi,$ $i$-th row of $R$ is $1$ at index $\pi(i)$ and $0$ elsewhere. This means that $R$ rotates the space by only permuting the axes. If we draw $U$ as the first $k$ columns of a random permutation matrix, we can show that the expectation is equal to $k/d\log\det(A^\top A).$ In other words, on average, the log-volume shrinks by a factor of $k/d,$ which makes sense. However, I don't know how much this deviates from the exact expectation.


I was wondering if this expectation can be derived more directly using the properties and symmetries of random rotation matrices, which will also hold when $k/d<1$ but not requiring $k/d\ll 1$?
